# How to implement custom suggesions using AutoComplete TextView in Android ?

Tags: android, autocomplete

How to implement Custom Suggestions ( sorting / filtering ) using AutoComplete TextView. like below image, i want to implement ,

[image]

means , suggestions comes if input character is present in the data array element, either it is not starts with the input character.

How to implement ?

Comment: I have tried above search functionality working with view stub,on addTextChangedListener. But how to override suggestions with autoCompleteTextView ?

Comment: see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19858843/how-to-dynamically-add-suggestions-to-autocompletetextview-with-preserving-chara